# Loop through 2D array and print results with format

Tags: c#

I have a simple 2D array that repeats the name of a staff and their corresponding department.

```
string[,] staffArray= new string[,] { { "StaffID", "Dept" }, { "StaffID", "Dept" }, { "StaffID", "Dept" }, { "StaffID", "Dept" } };
```

I want to print it back to back to get "Staff, Dept" as a result. However, I would like to do this via loop.

```
        Console.Write(staffArray[0, 0] + ", ");
        Console.WriteLine(staffArray[0, 1]);
        Console.Write(staffArray[1, 0] + ", ");
        Console.WriteLine(staffArray[1, 1]);
```

Prints:

Staff, Dept

Staff, Dept

Can someone explain how I could achieve this result with a loop?

Comment: [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) is your friend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     string[,] multiPropertySelect = new string[,] { { "StaffID", "Dept" }, { "StaffID", "Dept" }, { "StaffID", "Dept" }, { "StaffID", "Dept" } };

     for (int x = 0; x < multiPropertySelect.GetLength(0); ++x)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", multiPropertySelect[x, 0], multiPropertySelect[x, 1]));
     }

     Console.ReadKey();
```